# How to Write to excel in currency format in SSIS?

Tags: excel, ssis, format, etl, currency

We have database query with 3 feilds we are using SSIS to put result in excel. We want one column to take currency with prefix $. How can this be done?
E.g. data from database
Business year Revenue
Retail 2016 100025.35
Wholesale 2017 32000.00
HyperMarkey 2017 54700000.67

When in excel want Revenue in currency format

Comment: Please add some sample data and required output

Answer (score 0):

I guess your source database is MSSQL:

[image: Flow path]

You can use a query similar to this in data source , in source select data access mode from sql command, instead of table name , use the query.

```
select Trans_time, '$'+ cast(Value as varchar(50)) Value
 from testtable
```

Use `data Conversion` if necessary , you should get the required output with `$` sign prefixed to values

```
Sample output: 

Trans_time  Value
    6     $500.00
    12    $800.00
    12    $1000.00
    25    $1200.00
    25    $1800.00
    26    $600.00
    26    $300.00
```

Comment: Format in excel becomes General... we want it currency.

Comment: Rephrase it again please, u mean u will have different currencies in the table

Comment: The default format Excel taken with running ssis package is usually General, Format excel sheet manually to obtain column specific formats

Answer (score 0):

I think that the only way that you can achieve this is by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library within a Script Task that change the column format using `NumberFormat` property.

```
workSheet.Range["B1", "B2"].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#,###.00 $";
```

**Additional Information**

- [Formatting Excel cells (currency)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338156/formatting-excel-cells-currency)